# Why can´t I save an object when I am using AUTH_USER_MODEL parameter?

Tags: django, django-views, django-1.5

I just migrated to Django 1.5. But I am having a some difficulties to work with `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. Look the following example, I just can't update a value in the database. What I am doing wrong?

**Test 1**

```
user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=3)
user.email
u'zzzzz@gmail.com'
user.is_active
False

user.is_active = True
user.save()

user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=3)
user.is_active
False
```

**Test 2**

```
user.email
u'zzzzz@gmail.com'
user.email='blah@blah.com'
user.save()

user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=3)
user.email
u'zzzzz@gmail.com'
```

**Teste 3** The same happens with MyUser model

```
from myuser.models import MyUser
a = MyUser.objects.get(id=3)
a.is_active
False
a.is_active = True
a.save()
a = MyUser.objects.get(id=3)
a.is_active
False
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the `id` of the `user` that you change is 3?

Comment: Yes, it's 3. >>> user = get_user_model().objects.get(id=3)
>>> print user.id
3

Comment: Can you post your models code?

Comment: +1 for comment asking for the model code. Almost seems like maybe you are overriding the save method, but forgetting to call `super()`

Answer (score 1):

@Catherine and @Sid were correctly! Thanks Guys!

In my save method I forget to indent super().

It was:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if not self.hash:
        now = time.localtime(time.time())
        time_formatted=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", now)
        hash="%s%s" % (time_formatted, self.email)
        self.hash=hashlib.sha1(hash).hexdigest()
        super(MyUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

when the correct is:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.hash:
        now = time.localtime(time.time())
        time_formatted=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", now)
        hash="%s%s" % (time_formatted, self.email)
        self.hash=hashlib.sha1(hash).hexdigest()
    super(MyUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```